# Migrate from uTorrent to KTorrent

Tags: ubuntu, utorrent, ktorrent

How would I transfer data from uTorrent(windows) to KTorrent(Ubuntu)? I have hundreds of files that were seeding in windows, all fully downloaded.

Comment: Just a note, you can run utorrent in wine.

Comment: Would it have same performance for large number of torrents/connections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope that there is a more elegant way than one I'm going to suggest, but if nothing comes up, this could help.

Make sure that windows disk is visible from Ubuntu. Get all .torrent files for torrents you are seeding in µTorrent. Then open them in KTorrent one by one. Once KTorrent asks you where you want to save files, chose same location where you downloaded them from windows. KTorrent should detect percentage downloaded and continue downloading further. Since the downloads are complete it should start seeding.

Of course, try this out with smallest torrent first, just in case something goes wrong.

**EDIT**

Preliminary results:

**First step** for me was to open KTorrent and open configure KTorrent settings. There under Application there should be option Default save location. Set it to location where data from torrents is downloaded. After that button labeled OK is to be clicked. Then we proceed to next step.

**Second step** is to test settings. Open favorite terminal application. I personally like Konsole. Then type:

```
ktorrent \path\to\torrent\file\foo.torrent --silent
```

This will add torrent to ktorrent and start downloading it with out user intervention. Process will be run in background, so same shell can be used again. It should detect that torrent is already downloaded and switch to seeding mode. `ktorent --silent` can be run even if ktorrent is already running and will add any new torrents to running instance.

Try this out and report how it works.

**Third step**: Bash script which should detect all .torrent files in a directory and call ktorrent for each of them :

After completing first two steps, and making sure that they worked correctly, open you favorite console application and navigate to directory where the .torrent files are.
then type following:

```
gedit script.sh
```

gedit window will open. Paste following code in it:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in  *.torrent #this will list through every .torrent in working directory
do
    echo "Proccessing $f file..."
    ktorrent "$f"  --silent #this will call ktorrent for every .torrent file detected
done
```

Click save. The script will be saved. Next thing we need to do is to allow it to execute.

Type:

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

This will make script executable. Finally, run it by typing:

```
./script.sh
```

It should add all torrents in directory to ktorrent. This way you'll save the effort needed for manually adding hundreds of torrents.

Comment: This is the same thing you'd do when moving to *any*  torrent client

Comment: @Sathya Indeed it is. That's why I hope that someone will provide better answer. Doing this procedure for hundreds of files can take thousands of seconds and can be impractical.

Comment: So there is no automated way? Considering that I have many of them, it will be not easy to add one by one...

Comment: @Michael AFAIK there is no automated way :(

Comment: @Michael There may be a way to make a shell script to do most of the work. It mainly depends on the logic used to store torrents on windows side. If it is easy to determine directory in which data are on windows from .torrent file name, it could be possible to make a script which would add torrents to KTorrent. I'll take a look at KTorrents mas page and see if something is available. If something could be done, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @AndrejaKo: yes, it's easy. the directory for windows is `%APPDATA%\roaming\utorrent` which contains all torrents and two .dat files, assuming for some states and root folders. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Michael I meant the directories where the downloaded files are stored. Anyway, I'll take a look and report the results.

Comment: @Michael I added the bash script.

Answer (score 1):

Just to note instead of opening a file saving a script making it executable and such you can just execute the whole thing in one line like this:

```
for f in  *.torrent; do echo "Processing $f";ktorrent "$f"  --silent;done
```

Just make sure you are in the directory with torrent files when you do.